# Using Composer to install mailparser, why am I getting an error that allow_url_fopen must be enabled when it already is enabled?

Tags: composer-php, email-parsing

I am trying to install [this PHP mailparser](https://github.com/php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser).  I have Composer installed and the required mailparse extension is also installed. However, when I run:

```
composer require php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser
```

I get the following error:

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]   The
>   "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be
>   downloaded   : allow_url_fopen must be enabled in php.ini (https://
>   wrapper is disabled   in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0
>   failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found)

However, I've checked php.ini and it clearly says it's enabled, i.e.

```
allow_url_fopen = On
```

How could I get that specific of an error about needing to enable allow_url_fopen even though it definitely IS enabled?

Comment: Are you sure that you edited the right `php.ini` file? You can run `php --ini` to get the locations of all loaded ini files. You can also run `php -i` to check the current configuration.

Comment: I ran php -i and it's saying allow_url_fopen is set to OFF.  So I guess I didn't edit the right one.  I only see one though (in my public_html folder). Very strange.  I have contacted my hosting company to see if there is a universal php.ini file somewhere that I can't find.  Thanks for the feedback

Comment: What are the options when you don't have access to the system php.ini?

Answer (score 0):

Run this command:

```
php -d allow_url_fopen=on <composer_path> <composer_arguments>
```

Replace `<composer_path>` with the direct path to the composer executable (e.g. `/opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer`) and `<composer_arguments>` with the arguments you are passing to composer (e.g. `require php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser`).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
php -d allow_url_fopen=1 /opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer install
```